# Correct method for setting URL keys in a multi-language store?

Tags: multistore, url, seo

I have a multi-language store with two views, EN and DE.
I use the store view in the URL, so a page might look like:

- http://www.mysite.de/en/news.html

When I create the DE version (which I do by changing view and editing the text in my pages), do I need (or should I) create unique URL keys, or is it enough that the country code is changing. In other words, which of these is best?

- http://www.mysite.de/de/news.html
- http://www.mysite.de/de/news-de.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your question mostly relates to SEO value, not how to technically do it in Magento. So we are just talking about semantics here. The language prefix already makes the URL unique, plus it uniquely identifies the language for that page. So this already is a plus for SEO.

Having an additional "news-de" would not be necessary - the language is already specified and the "-de" suffix does not tell anything new about the "news" part either. Because it is unneeded, it is actually bad practice to add it in there.

A URL like "/de/nachrichten" would be making much more sense: The "news" is translated into German ("nachrichten") and this not only points out to searchbots which language is used: It also gives added value to German readers. However, it would only make sense if the actual page itself (so the German translation of some product) actually is German.

In short: Try to use an URL key that directly matches the product name that is used on that page.

Comment: thanks Great answer. It only becomes a little more unclear, if the same word is used in English and German, ie Partner or Shop. But then, the /en/ or /de/ is play, so it's still unique.

Comment: I think in that case /en/shop/ and /de/shop/ are both fine. The URL should match the content. The URL should not contain something different than the URL. So in case of a German Shop page, it might be better to give that page a title "Laden", which then reflect to the URL, instead of trying to optimizing the URL and not its content. My 50 cents ;)